# android show incoming call dialog

Tags: android, call

Is it possible to make android show the incoming call dialog. Like forcing a PHONE_STATE_RINGING.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android incoming call screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486547/android-incoming-call-screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if it is possible, but there are a few applicaiton out there which mimick this, creating a fake call.

Take a look at [Fake call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716241)

Answer (score 1):

[android incoming call screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486547/android-incoming-call-screen)