# Fake Call Functionality (Android)

Tags: android

I want to make my app able to make fake incoming call . This should ring and be able to receive but this is not actually a call.

I already know i can make my own activity and make the dialer and receiving etc etc and do the fake call.

but is there any other way to do it. if not what would be best approach.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716241/fake-call-in-android

Comment: thanks . i will have a look at it.

Comment: hey @NiravRanpara i saw the question you told as i have duplicated . this question do not suggest any concrete answer. and the links in the question are not working .

Comment: @NiravRanpara non of the two answer in the question you are saying as duplicate are full . one has missing link and other has incomplete answer. please do check before making any flag that the question is good or not.